# Interop between Javascript "Fritz Schneider's Rijndael Reference Implementation"  and .NET

Tags: c#, javascript, cryptography, aes, rijndael

I am using the javascript Fritz Schneider's Rijndael Reference Implementation. I want to decrypt the result in C#.

The input variables provided in Javascript Rijndael function are

```
function rijndaelEncrypt(plaintext, key, mode) {}
```

where plaintext is the text to be encrypted, key is the encryption key, and mode selects either ECB or CBC. The mode we are using is ECB.

**Now, for Microsoft Rijndael implementation, what should I use for the Initialization Vector to decrypt this?**

For the record, the whole javascript encryption goes like this.

```
function rijndaelEncrypt(plaintext, key, mode) {
  var i, aBlock;
  var bpb = blockSizeInBits / 8;          // bytes per block
  var ct;                                 // ciphertext

  if (!plaintext || !key)
    return;
  if (key.length*8 != keySizeInBits)
    return; 
  if (mode == "CBC")
    ct = getRandomBytes(bpb);             // get IV
  else {
    mode = "ECB";
    ct = new Array();
  }

  // convert plaintext to byte array and pad with zeros if necessary. 
  plaintext = formatPlaintext(plaintext);

  var expandedKey = new keyExpansion(key);

  for (var block=0; block<plaintext.length / bpb; block++) {
    aBlock = plaintext.slice(block*bpb, (block+1)*bpb);
    if (mode == "CBC")
      for (var i=0; i<bpb; i++) 
        aBlock[i] ^= ct[block*bpb + i];
    ct = ct.concat(AESencrypt(aBlock, expandedKey));
  }

  return ct;
}
```

Thanks. Help much appreciated.

Comment: Questions typically end with a question mark. It looks like this: `?`.  What is _your_ question? Do you want us to write the C# equivalent code for you? That's not what SO is for.

Comment: MS RijndaelManaged function asks for initialization vector. The javascript function doesn't have an intialization vector. How can I ensure the cross program compbatitbilty? What would be my initialization vector. As for the implemetation, I can write the encryption myself, once I know the initialization vector?

Answer (score 1):

First, ECB mode has no initialization vector. I think you can pass null, an empty array or an array filled by 0 to your RijndaelManaged object.

For your CBC mode implementation here, the initialization vector is the first 128-bit block of the ciphertext array.

```
 if (mode == "CBC")
    ct = getRandomBytes(bpb);             // get IV
```

These are filled with random bytes on encryption, and read from here on decryption.

I'm not sure if RijndaelManaged will output the initialization vector for you, simply have a look at the output size. If not, add it yourself.

Comment: ECB mode is not secure.  Unless this is just a learning exercise you should use CBC mode (or CTR mode if it is available).

Comment: CTR mode is not available in javascript. only ECB. and ECB mode is implemented application wise using JavaScript.

Comment: Given ECB mode it is not difficult to construct your own version of CTR.  All the modes are built round ECB.  The question says that CBC mode is also available, use that in preference to ECB.